# Sql query with pivot and count

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            column1,
            column2,
            column3
        FROM
            table
        WHERE value NOT IN(
                'v1',
                'v2',
            )
            AND column1 = 'c1'
            AND column2 IN(
                'c2',
                'c21',
                'c22',

            )
    ) pivot(
        MAX(column) FOR(c) IN(
               'c2' ,
               'c21' ,
               'c22'  ));
```

Now I want to add this script to count the other columns:

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column1='c1' AND column2='c2'
AND column in(
SELECT a.column FROM table a, table b WHERE a.column1='c1' AND a.column2='c2'
AND b.column NOT IN (c1, c2));
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Your "existing" query is syntactically wrong already. Please create your own small table with a bit of test data and test the query on it before you post it here. In the query, you select `column1` through `colum3` but then in pivot you have `max(column)` (there is no "`column`" to take max over) and "`for c in ...`" (there is no column `c` either). We can guess at what you meant, but we shouldn't have to do the work for you.